# Wizard/Stepper in mobile app: "abort wizard" and "back button"

Tags: mobile, wizard, app

I have an 8-step wizard in my app and want the user to be able to abort the whole wizard.

My app has a title bar and usually, the top left icon is either a "burger icon" (opening the main drawer) or a "back arrow"

For my wizard I thought it would be better to deviate from this behavior and display an [X]-icon allowing to abort the wizard instead.

The user has 2 options to go "back" already: the wizards "< BACK"-button and the back triangle from the mobile's main navigation. Adding a third feels kind of redundant.

Now to my question(s):

a) Is the "X" icon with functionality "abort wizard" the most intuitive/expected option for the title bar

b) Upon pressing the "X"-icon to abort the wizard: would you expect a confirm dialog along the lines of "aborting the wizard will delete all previously filled in data, are you sure" or is the "X" icon sufficiently clear

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wizard/Stepper in mobile app: navigation options in final review step of wizard](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/142244/wizard-stepper-in-mobile-app-navigation-options-in-final-review-step-of-wizard)

Comment: This is a different question for the same wizard but I am happy with Gerda's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that a back arrow in the top left corner would probably cause confusion here. The X could work, though I'd test this. 
As the consequences fo pressing the X are pretty harsh  (losing all the data), I'd recommend a confirmation dialog.

Please avoid the word "abort" in this context. It has been common practice to use "Cancel" instead for quite some time now.